# List installed products & components using powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, deployment

i came across a situation i want to mount a content database in a new environment that i don't know what was installed previously there.
Using powershell how i know what installations installed in sharepoint 2013 environment.
Example:
language packs
service packs
cumulative updates

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you looking for

```
$listApps=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where {$_.IdentifyingNumber -like “*90150000-*”}
    $listApps | Sort -Property Name | ft -Autosize
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/04/20/powershell-script-to-display-version-info-for-installed-sharepoint-product-and-language-packs/

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-listing-all-installed.html

Answer (score 2):

Execute `Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | where-object { $_.PsPath -like "*\Office*" } | foreach {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}  | fl DisplayName, DisplayVersion` one-liner in SharePoint Management Shell and then look up build numbers at [Todd Klindt's site](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346).

Adapted that from Stefan Goßner`s [post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/04/20/powershell-script-to-display-version-info-for-installed-sharepoint-product-and-language-packs/) long time ago. Refer to original for additional information.

Comment: let me try this and get back to here

Comment: Please let me know it this fits your requirement. Try replacing `"*\Office*"` substring with `"*1000-0000000FF1CE}"` to get component-level output - more detailed, harder to read